# My signal handler sample is not working

Tags: c, linux

**1.I have written a piece of sample code and that will catch SIGALRM signal exit the main process.**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<sys/signal.h>

static int sig_flag=0;
static void mysignal(int sig)
{
        sig_flag=1;
}

void installsignal(int sig,void( *signalhandler)(int))
{
    struct sigaction action={0};
    action.sa_handler=signalhandler;
    action.sa_flags=0;
        sigemptyset(&action.sa_mask);
        if(sigaction(sig,&action,NULL)<0)
        {
                printf("can not catch signal signum:%d\n",sig);
        }
}
main()
{
        installsignal(SIGALRM,mysignal);
        if(sig_flag==1)
        {
                printf("\n Signal has been caought\n");
                exit(0);
        }
        while(1)
        {
                printf("\nHello world\n");
                sleep(1);
        }
        exit(0);
}
```

**2.When i  have changed my program as given below then its works:-**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<sys/signal.h>

static int sig_flag=0;
static void mysignal(int sig)
{
 sig_flag=1;
}

void installsignal(int sig,void( *signalhandler)(int))
{
    struct sigaction action={0};
    action.sa_handler=signalhandler;
    action.sa_flags=0;
    sigemptyset(&action.sa_mask);
    if(sigaction(sig,&action,NULL)<0)
    {
     printf("can not catch signal signum:%d\n",sig);
    }
}
main()
{
    installsignal(SIGALRM,mysignal);
    while(1)
    {
     printf("\nHello world\n");
     if(sig_flag==1)
     {
      printf("\n Signal has been caought\n");
      exit(0);
     }
     sleep(1);
    }
        exit(0);
}
```

**Why first one sample code is not working**

Comment: Did you ever get it to work? If so, please accept an answer. Doing so will help others in future

Answer (score 4):

You got the control loop wrong. You never ask for the flag inside, so how would you want that you notice that the signal has been caught.

Besides that Basile is correct, only use `sig_atomic_t` for communication with a signal handler.

Answer (score 3):

You should define

```
 static volatile sig_atomic_t sig_flag=0;
```

Read about [**volatile** variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_variable) and [sig_atomic_t](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/csignal/sig_atomic_t/) and read carefully [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)

Of course you need to test `sig_flag` *inside* your loop or use [pause(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pause.2.html) or [sigsuspend(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigsuspend.2.html). Maybe you want an [event loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) using [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html). Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/), [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html), and about the Linux specific [signalfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html) and [timerfd_create(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html)....

Comment: +1, but this is not the thing that causes the unwanted behavior.